# Adding class to nth child and its child using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a structure like

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="gallery-item-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which repeats itself n number of times. I want to assign a class `full` to `gallery-item-wrapper` and `gallery-item` divs and remove `portrait`. Till now, I have been able to target the `gallery-item-wrapper` div but can't target its inner child. I have used

```
$(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper:nthchild(3n+2)").addClass("full");
```

but this doesn't work for the inner child. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: To be explicit can you show us the HTML you want to have as the end-result of your JavaScript use? Do you want the the `<!-- content -->` to remain? Do you want just the `portrait` class-name to be removed, or the element itself?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, how is that not clear? I have already received the apt answer and awarded the point too.

Comment: Because language is ambiguous and can be interpreted in different ways. But you got lucky, so great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to address the `gallery-item`s which are the 3n+2 child of its parents, one needs to use the following code:

```
$(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper .gallery-item:nth-child(3n+2)")
```

instead of what you have tried:

```
$(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper:nthchild(3n+2)")
```

Second, you can in a single line command remove the `portrait`class and add the `full` class:

```
.removeClass('portrait').addClass('full');
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btn').click(function(){
    var children = $(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper .gallery-item:nth-child(3n+2)");
    children.addClass("full").removeClass('portrait');
  });
});
```

```css
.full{
  width: 100%;
}
.portrait{
  width: 50%;
}
.full, .portrait{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="gallery-item-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 3
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 4
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 5
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item portrait">
      Content 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Make the 3n+2 items Full</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("full");
```

Will only add it to the .gallery-item-wrapper, so you'll have to add another line

```
$(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper:nth-child(3n+2) .gallery-item").addClass("full");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```js
var wrapper = $(".gallery-wrapper .gallery-item-wrapper:nth-child(3n+2)");
var subWrapper = wrapper.find('.gallery-item');
wrapper.add(subWrapper).removeClass('portrait').addClass('full');
```